# I need to calculate the time until a users next birthday

Tags: php, html, date

I'm a student currently enrolled in a PHP course, and our instructor has told us to create code that would accept a users birthday and then calculate how many days from today is their next birthday. I completely understand how to calculate the time between two dates, but since I want only the amount of days until the users birthday, it gets tricky. I've searched for this question but all the answers seem to just calculate the time between years.

Example: 
Input: 11/14/1985
Today's Date is 11/9/2016
Output (should be): "You have 5 days until your next Birthday"

THIS IS MY EDITED CODE:

```
<?php
$johnsBirthday = $_GET ['JohnBday'];
$jakesBirthday = $_GET ['JakeBday'];
$john_bday = new DateTime($_GET['JohnBday']);
$jake_bday = new DateTime($_GET['JakeBday']);
$today_date = new DateTime();

 switch (true) {
    case ($john_bday < $today_date) :
    $today_date->setDate($john_bday->format('Y'), $today_date-    >format('m'), $today_date->format('d'));
    break;

    case ($today_date < $john_bday) :
    $john_bday->setDate($today_date->format('Y'), $john_bday->format('m'),     $john_bday->format('d'));
    break;
}

switch (true) {
    case ($today_date < $jake_bday) :
    $jake_bday->setDate($today_date->format('Y'), $jake_bday->format('m'),     $jake_bday->format('d'));
    break;

    case ($jake_bday < $today_date) :
    $jake_bday->setDate($today_date->format('Y'), $jake_bday->format('m'), $jake_bday->format('d'));
    break;      
}
$john_interval = $john_bday->diff($today_date);
$john_diff = $john_interval->format('%a');
echo "John you have $john_diff days until your next Birthday</br>";
$jake_interval = $jake_bday->diff($today_date);
$jake_diff = $jake_interval->format('%a');
echo "Jake you have $jake_diff days until your next Birthday</br>";

if ($johnsBirthday < $jakesBirthday)
{
    echo "John is older than Jake</br>";
}
elseif ($johnsBirthday > $jakesBirthday)
{
    echo "Jake is older than John</br>";
}
else
{
    echo "Jake and John are twins";
}






?>
```

Thanks for the assistance in advance,
Tiffany

Answer (score 1):

This should work on your scenario if you're using `PHP 5.3 >`, this is one of the most accurate way of calculating the difference. I have used variable names properly for your clear understanding.

```
 $input_date = new DateTime('1985-11-14');
 $today_date = new DateTime();

 switch (true) {
    case ($input_date < $today_date) :
        $today_date->setDate($input_date->format('Y'), $today_date->format('m'), $today_date->format('d'));
        break;

    case ($today_date < $input_date) :
        $input_date->setDate($today_date->format('Y'), $input_date->format('m'), $input_date->format('d'));
        break;
}

$interval = $input_date->diff($today_date);
$diff = $interval->format('%a');
$output = "You have $diff days until your next Birthday";
echo $output;
```

**Edit:** This should be your code

```
$johnsBirthday = '1985-11-15';
$jakesBirthday = '2986-11-30';
$john_bday = new DateTime($johnsBirthday);
$jake_bday = new DateTime($jakesBirthday);
$today_date = new DateTime();

switch (true) {
    case ($john_bday < $today_date) :
    $today_date->setDate($john_bday->format('Y'), $today_date->format('m'), $today_date->format('d'));
    break;

    case ($today_date < $john_bday) :
    $john_bday->setDate($today_date->format('Y'), $john_bday->format('m'), $john_bday->format('d'));
    break;
}

switch (true) {
    case ($today_date < $jake_bday) :
    $jake_bday->setDate($today_date->format('Y'), $jake_bday->format('m'),$jake_bday->format('d'));
    break;

    case ($jake_bday < $today_date) :
    $today_date->setDate($jake_bday->format('Y'), $jake_bday->format('m'), $jake_bday->format('d'));
    break;
}
$john_interval = $john_bday->diff($today_date);
$john_diff = $john_interval->format('%a');
echo "John you have $john_diff days until your next Birthday</br>";
$jake_interval = $jake_bday->diff($today_date);
$jake_diff = $jake_interval->format('%a');
echo "Jake you have $jake_diff days until your next Birthday</br>";

if ($johnsBirthday < $jakesBirthday)
{
    echo "John is older than Jake</br>";
}
elseif ($johnsBirthday > $jakesBirthday)
{
    echo "Jake is older than John</br>";
}
else
{
    echo "Jake and John are twins";
}
```

Comment: So I have edited the code as you have instructed, but when I run this code the number of days calculated are a bit off. So if the birthday is really 30 days away, the program may give me 33 days away.

Comment: @TiffanyIwinyoulose check my edit, I guess you have miss used the `$jake_bday` on your second `switch` statement :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using date times.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

```
// create the birthday and a copy to add a year to for the next
$datetime1 = new DateTime($_GET['JohnBday']);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($_GET['JohnBday']);

date_add($datetime2, date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 year'));

$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a PHP function just for that called date_diff. Here is an example straight from the PHP manual..

```
<?php
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```